# Why am I seeing all these weird 'loginid' requests?

Tags: urls

I've been monitoring the access log for one of my Wordpress sites, and I'm seeing a lot of requests like this:

> /?loginid=df01ec6de1

I'll see a long series of these coming from one particular IP address, each with a different string after the equals sign. Then I'll see another long series of similar requests from a different IP. This happens throughout the day.

It looks like a hack attempt of some kind, but I haven't found anything to confirm that.